# How to edit CSS / Styling of Firefox Reader View

Tags: css, firefox, styling, firefox-reader-view

I want to include a font of my choice in Firefox Reader View Styling.

Please let me know if Firefox uses a local CSS file for styling or it is located somewhere else?

Moreover What is the CSS File name Firefox uses for Reader View and how can I edit the same.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Ain't the whole point with reader view that the content is rendered without the developers interference ? 
There is a css-file `aboutReader.css` included. 
More suitable would be to ask a question on the  project it self => https://github.com/mozilla/readability

Answer (score 15):

You find the CSS file for the "Firefox Reader View" under the path 
`cd /home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE_FOLDER>/chrome/userContent.css` 
only if you already did set it up:

1. Enter in your Firefox URL-search-bar: `about:support`.
2. Open your *Profile Folder* by selecting `Show Folder`.
3. Create a new folder inside your *profile folder* called `chrome`.
4. Navigate into `chrome` and create a new plain-text file called `userContent.css`
5. Edit `userContent.css` according to your CSS preferences.
6. In new Firefox profiles, starting from Firefox 69, you additionally have to enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` in `about:config`, cf. [Firefox 69: userChrome.css and userContent.css disabled by default](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/).

---

In my case it looked like the following:

```
cd /home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE_FOLDER>/
mkdir chrome
cd ./chrome
touch userContent.css
```

CSS-Example:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("about:reader") {
  body.dark {
    color: salmon !important;
    background-color: black !important;
  }
  body.light {
    color: #222 !important;
    background-color: #EEE !important;
  }
  body.sepia {
    color: #5B4636 !important;
    background-color: #F4ECD8 !important;
  }

  body.serif {
    font-family: serif !important;
  }
  body.sans-serif {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
  }
}
```

See [this Reference](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-reader-view-theme-firefox/) for further explanations.

Comment: What if I'm on Windows?

Comment: In new Firefox profiles, starting from Firefox 69, you additionally have to enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` in _about:config,_ cf. [Firefox 69: userChrome.css and userContent.css disabled by default](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/05/24/firefox-69-userchrome-css-and-usercontent-css-disabled-by-default/).

Comment: @mach: This doesn't seem to work anymore: _userContent.css_ is ignored. Too bad, since the default typewriter fonts are unreadable on certain screens.

Comment: This seems like a lot just to change the font. Why is Mozilla so scared to allow users customizing their reader experience?

Comment: @MerajalMaksud I would presume `%APPDATA%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>/chrome/userContent.css`

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to add or change .css, follow these steps:

1. In address bar, type **`about:config`**, then click the button to accept the risk.
2. In the search box, type or paste the new preference name: **`pdfjs.viewerCssTheme`**
3. Double-click to edit and set the value to **2** for a dark theme, then click the blue checkmark button to save the change. (0 = default,  1 = light).